# how do I convert $4\sinθ_1-5\sinθ_2$ and $4\cosθ_1+5\cosθ_2$ to their sum-to-product identity?

Tags: trigonometry

so the sum to product identity is given as: 
$$\cos u + \cos v = 2 \cos(\frac{1}{2}(u + v)) \cos (\frac{1}{2}(u − v))$$

$$\cos u − \cos v = −2 \sin(\frac{1}{2}(u + v)) \sin(\frac{1}{2}(u − v))$$

$$\sin u + \sin v = 2 \sin(\frac{1}{2}(u + v)) \cos(\frac{1}{2}(u − v))$$

$$\sin u − \sin v = 2 \sin(\frac{1}{2}(u − v)) \cos(\frac{1}{2}(u + v))$$

but what if the $\sin$ and $\cos$ in has numerical coefficients like this:

$4\sinθ_1-5\sinθ_2$ and $4\cosθ_1+5\cosθ_2$

what will be its equivalent identity?
(sorry bad english)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: what do you want to prove?

Comment: well I'm suppose to get the values of the two angles. i figured maybe converting it from sum to product will help me get the values. I already solved it using a different solution but I'm curious if it can be solve using the sum to product identity @alexjo

Comment: but you don't have any equality or value...what is your original question?

Comment: The two equations are: 160sinθ1-200sinθ2=0 and 160cosθ1+200cosθ2=300 @alexjo

Comment: what, you are trying to solve these simultaneously? I am not sure that what I answered below will be any help with that: with unknown - hence arbitrary - values of $\theta$ you will not in general be able to factorize fully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to group them like this:
$$ 4\sin \theta_1 - 5\sin \theta_2 = 4.5 (\sin\theta_1 - \sin\theta_2) - 0.5 (\sin\theta_2 + \sin\theta_2) $$
then proceed to transform each group separately, and look for a common factor in the two products to factorize fully.

**EDIT:** Note that for arbitrary values of $\theta_{1,2}$ full factorization will not be possible. Usually this trick is used in problems where the angles have been chosen to conveniently "work out."

For what you really want to do, I would just say $\cos\theta_1 = x_1$ and $\cos\theta_2 = x_2$ and switch from sines to cosines in the first equation by squaring it: $\sin^2\theta_1 = 1 - \cos^2\theta_1 = 1- x_1^2$. Then solve a pair of equations, one linear, one non-linear, which is fairly straightforward.

Comment: will try that. thanks!